# CsvHelper parse text in a table which is not delimited

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Here is my data set which has come from a command which i have no control over the output:

```
BOOLEANCOLUMN   NAME             CLUSTER          AUTHINFO
                someName         someCluster      SomeMoreData   
*               name2            Data2            Data2
```

I want to be able to convert this into a class to work with the data, I am trying to use CSVHelper however they headers are not delimited, they are spaced to format the data to be human readable.
I currently have a mapping class as so:

```
public ContextMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Name).Name("NAME");
            Map(m => m.AuthInfo).Name("AUTHINFO");
            Map(m => m.Cluster).Name("CLUSTER");
            Map(m => m.BooleanColumn).Name("BOOLEANCOLUMN");

        }
```

but i am getting the exception :

CsvHelper.MissingFieldException: 'Field with name 'NAME' does not exist. You can ignore missing fields by setting MissingFieldFound to null.'

Question: How can I parse this data to a class?

Comment: Can you just replace multiple spaces with a delimiter before processing?

Comment: @stuartd thanks for you response, could you post an example answer of how you would parse it correclty with adding in a delimiter as i'm unsure how would I do that for the empty column.

Comment: Sorry, should have noticed that. Do the spaces follow a consistent pattern in every file?

Comment: Hi @stuartd the emptyColumn may have an asterik in the data column

Comment: Is the empty column always the first one? Or can any of the columns have empty values? Maybe it would help if you showed a bit more of the data.

Comment: @stuartd added another row, these 2 are representative of the rest of the data, it's only that column that will be empty

Comment: It seems to me that what you need is a fixed width file reader, e.g. [FixedWidthFileReader](https://csvreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FixedWidthFileReader/) (I haven't tried it). Or you can use the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-fixed-width-text-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the documentation and it seems the developer has got plans to implement a fixed width parser but hasn't made it yet.

To get around this issue, I created the following method to convert the data to delimited in code instead:

```
public static string ConvertFixedWidthToCsv(string data)
    {
        var rows = data.Split(
            new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
            StringSplitOptions.None
        );

        var returnRows = new List<string>();

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row))
            {
                continue;
            }
            var parsed = Regex.Replace(row, @"\s+", ",");

            returnRows.Add(parsed);
        }

        return String.Join("\r\n", returnRows);
    }
```